# Arch Linux - NetworkManager unable to setup hotspot

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, wifi-hotspot, ad-hoc-network

I have network-manager and nm-applet installed on arch linux. I'm using Gnome desktop. When I try to set-up hotspot using GUI I get an error stating "Activation of network failed". This is what I have in my `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connection/Hotspot`

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=00b96273-0d3d-4430-bacc-280f2cd0c19d
type=wifi
autoconnect=false
permissions=
secondaries=

[wifi]
hidden=false
mac-address=AC:B5:7A:85:D2:DA
mac-address-blacklist=
mac-address-randomization=0
mode=ap
seen-bssids=
ssid=name

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=password

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

I tried connecting using `nmcli con up id Hotspot` but it gave me the same error. I made sure the extra services like `network.service` or `net-auto-wireless.service` are disabled (They were already disabled).

Can anyone help me setting up a hotspot with network-manager.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just checking.  You are not trying to make a hotspot with the same network interface that is currently connected to a wireless network, right?

Comment: @grochmal - No. I have ethernet connected and I need ad-hoc on wireless. Anyway it seems I found the solution. Since arch doesn't ship with some packages, it had been difficult to find what was missing. I didn't have dnsmasq installed. So, now I installed it and it works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution. I was missing some dependencies required to start ad-hoc. Here is the list of dependencies that `network-manager` requires.

```
Depends On      : libnm-glib  iproute2  polkit  wpa_supplicant  libsoup  libmm-glib  libnewt  libndp  libteam
Optional Deps   : dnsmasq: connection sharing
                  bluez: Bluetooth support [installed]
                  openresolv: resolvconf support [installed]
                  ppp: dialup connection support
                  rp-pppoe: ADSL support
                  dhclient: External DHCP client
                  modemmanager: cellular network support
```

`dnsmasq` was missing in my case. After I installed it, it started working.

Comment: Good point, you might also add the reference to the [arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Ad-hoc) that points to the add-hoc dependencies.